# Convert time interval to mixed units without leading zeros

Tags: date-and-time, units

Let's say I have time intervals in seconds. I am looking for a method that produces the following conversions:

`3660` => `1 hour 1 minute 0 seconds`
`1810` => `30 minutes 10 seconds` (not `0 hours 30 minutes 10 seconds`)

I should be able to specify the set of units(e.g. adding days or milliseconds, not just HMS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo[s_] := #[[;; , {1}, FirstPosition[#[[1, 1]], Except[0], {0}, 
        Heads -> False][[1]] ;;]] & @
  UnitConvert[Quantity[s, "Seconds"], MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]]

foo /@ {5000, 3000, 10}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no clue what happens before the `@`, but that is the correct answer.

Comment: I've hit a liiitle snag. I actually did want it spelled out, rather than getting a Quantity instance in the end. Of course it's easy to add a `ToString` call, but when my value is less than 60, Mathematica hits the recursion limit. E.g. this produces infinite recursion: `ToString[Quantity[20, MixedUnit[{"Seconds"}]]]`. It seems to happen when MixedUnit is called with only 1 unit. Could this be a bug?

Comment: I've discovered that this function behaves oddly/wrong with machine precision numbers. Compare `foo[600.]` to `UnitConvert[Quantity[600., "Seconds"], 
 MixedUnit[{"Minutes", "Seconds"}]]`.

Comment: @martixy I don't like this code either :) will try to address your comments later. Don't have time now.

Comment: Getting a displayable format is fairly easy: `ToString[QuantityForm[unitValue, "Abbreviation"]]`. The precision problem... not so much. One option is to coerce the value to what you need. The other, simpler one is to just `Round[]` it, if integer precision is enough. But I don't have anything better than conditionally covering edge cases.